# How to attach LSP debugging on Extention Host start, rather than manual attach

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-debugging, language-server-protocol

Hopefully 'There are no stupid questions apply' rule is in full effect, and I realise language server development is a little niche.

I have a bunch of startup code in my vscode extension I occasionally need to walk/debug, with a manual attach task, I obviously miss that code and because the Extention Host spawns the LSP instance, I have to attach to it manually as per the docs, is there any way to get the lsp to either wait or automatically attach to the debugger.

autoAttachChildProcesses wasn't a win, and --inspect-brk half got me there but just got me web packed js, no good without a source map.

I can feel myself working around this and just wondered if anyone else had done something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for folks in the same situation, you can do some magic in launch.json, the same level as "configurations", you can do something like this:

"compounds": [
{
"name": "Compound",
"configurations": ["launchConfig1","Attach to Server"]
}
],

That's going to net you a new compound launch config that will kick both the extension host start and the LSP server debugger attach, presuming you already have both the configs and create the compound launch config with the right labels

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, please do not forget to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will be helpful for other forum members.